# Use powershell array inside for loop

Tags: arrays, powershell, windows-server-2012

This is probably as basic a question as you can get regarding PowerShell but... I'm stuck on this nonetheless.

I am attempting to move a number of folder contents from a staging area on a remote server to our DEV server. To simplify the code, I put the staging locations in one array, and the folder names in a separate array.

I want to run a `for loop` and process the two as parallel arrays... simple right?

Here is the loop

```
Write-Host "Copying Files" -ForegroundColor Yellow
For ($i=0; $i -lt $periscopeServicesArray.Length; $i++)
{
    Write-Host "Copying $periscopeServicesArray[$i]" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    if(Test-Path -path "$domainpath\$periscopeWebServices\$periscopeServicesArray[$i]")
    {
        copy-item -Path "$stagingArray[$i]"\* -Destination "$domainpath\$periscopeWebServices\'$periscopeServicesArray[$i]'" -recurse -Force
    }
}
```

For some reason the `if` statment returns false everytime. If I print out the value that the `"$domainpath\$periscopeWebServices\$periscopeServicesArray[$i]"` is giving the statement to interpret this is what I get:

> E:\webcontent\InsideServices.dev.com\periscopeWebServices\periscopeRetrieveComments periscopeRetrieveGeneral periscopeRetrieveMasterSubs periscopeRetrieveProducers periscopeRetrieveProfiles 
>   periscopeRetrieveRelationships periscopeSearch[0]

The first two variables print properly however the entire contents of the array seem to be spilling out each time with the index value at the end.

Here are the variables/arrays as I've created them

```
#web services
$periscopeWebServices = "periscopeWebServices"
$periscopeRetrieveComments = "periscopeRetrieveComments"
$periscopeRetrieveGeneral = "periscopeRetrieveGeneral"
$periscopeRetrieveMasterSubs = "periscopeRetrieveMasterSubs"
$periscopeRetrieveProducers = "periscopeRetrieveProducers"
$periscopeRetrieveProfiles = "periscopeRetrieveProfiles"
$periscopeRetrieveRelationships = "periscopeRetrieveRelationships"
$periscopeSearch = "periscopeSearch"
$periscopeServicesArray = @($periscopeRetrieveComments, $periscopeRetrieveGeneral, 
                            $periscopeRetrieveMasterSubs, $periscopeRetrieveProducers, 
                            $periscopeRetrieveProfiles, $periscopeRetrieveRelationships, 
                            $periscopeSearch)


#staging areas
$stagingComments = "\\install\PeriscopeServices\periscopeWebServices\periscopeRetrieveComments"
$stagingGeneral = "\\install\PeriscopeServices\periscopeWebServices\periscopeRetrieveGeneral"
$stagingMasterSubs = "\\install\PeriscopeServices\periscopeWebServices\periscopeRetrieveMasterSubs"
$stagingProducers = "\\install\PeriscopeServices\periscopeWebServices\periscopeRetrieveProducers"
$stagingProfiles = "\\install\PeriscopeServices\periscopeWebServices\periscopeRetrieveProfiles"
$stagingRelationships = "\\install\PeriscopeServices\periscopeWebServices\periscopeRetrieveRelationships"
$stagingSearch = "\\install\PeriscopeServices\periscopeWebServices\periscopeSearch"
$stagingArray = @($stagingComments, $stagingGeneral, $stagingMasterSubs, $stagingProducers
                  $stagingProfiles, $stagingRelationships, $stagingSearch)

#server variables
$domain = "InsideServices.dev.com"
$directory = "E:\webcontent"
$domainpath = "$directory\$domain"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the way you're quoting the variables, you need to "escape" the array element accesses as `$($array[$elem])` when using in a string `"something $($isAt[$here])"`

```
Write-Host "Copying Files" -ForegroundColor Yellow
For ($i=0; $i -lt $periscopeServicesArray.Length; $i++)
{
    Write-Host "Copying $($periscopeServicesArray[$i])" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    if(Test-Path -path "$domainpath\$periscopeWebServices\$($periscopeServicesArray[$i])")
    {
        copy-item -Path "$($stagingArray[$i])"\* -Destination "$domainpath\$periscopeWebServices\$($periscopeServicesArray[$i])" -recurse -Force
    }
}
```